# WinApi unicode problem

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I have the code:

```
wchar_t* temp = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 1000 * sizeof(wchar_t));
wchar_t* temp2 = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 1000 * sizeof(wchar_t));

GetTempPathW(1000, temp);

GetTempFileNameW(temp, L"vdr", GetCurrentProcessId(), temp2);

HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, temp2);

MessageBoxW(0,temp2,0,0);
```

It should make a file "vdrXXXX.tmp" with XXXX to be the processs id. But it returns strange things. Like unicode symbols and then part of the path. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are freeing the memory before calling `MessageBox()`.

In any case, there's no need to use `HeapAlloc()`, just use `malloc()`. In fact, since `GetTempFileName()` has a maximum buffer size of `MAX_PATH`, it's easiest to do this with stack allocated buffers.